# Kubernetes admission controllers check

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

How can I check which admission controllers are enabled by default on the cluster using some command like kubectl.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using the following command
Kubectl cluster-info dump | grep -i admission

Comment: Hi, it does not provide the information about enabled admission controller.

Comment: " Kubectl cluster-info dump" should provide the info you need.. if it doesn't try finding options in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.manifest" or "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml". the other way to find this option  is by using docker inspect <api-server-container-id>

Comment: This answer is wrong. The word `admission` doesn't appear anywhere in the cluster info dump.

Answer (score 1):

There is no subcommand to list the enable admission controller with kubectl.

Nevertheless, you can get this information from kube-apiserver [admission controller enabled-by-default](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#which-plugins-are-enabled-by-default)

`kube-apiserver -h | grep enable-admission-plugins`

for k8s 1.16

- NamespaceLifecycle
- LimitRanger
- ServiceAccount
- TaintNodesByCondition
- Priority
- DefaultTolerationSeconds,
- DefaultStorageClass
- StorageObjectInUseProtection,
- PersistentVolumeClaimResize
- MutatingAdmissionWebhook,
- ValidatingAdmissionWebhook
- RuntimeClass
- ResourceQuota